# split string into several substring using indexes

Tags: perl

I have this string and hash:

**Input data:**

```
my $string = 'GATGCAGTTAGGCGTAGCAGAGTGAGACGACGACGATATTAGGACCCGGTAAGGCACAATATAGC';
my %coord_colors = (
  10 => "red",
  48 => "orange",
  60 => "purple",
);
```

What I want to do is to "open" the string at each hash key position, and insert the key-value. See the desired output to have an idea about what I'm trying to explain:

**Desired output:**

```
GATGCAGTTAredGGCGTAGCAGAGTGAGACGACGACGATATTAGGACCCGorangeGTAAGGCACAATpurpleATAGC
```

I know how the substr and split functions, but I'm not inspired about how to divide a string in several parts "simultaneously" and then introduce another string, and finally join. I've thought about doing a loop, and change positions in the has while I add the first positions but I would like to know the best approach to figure out this task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) as an lvalue and start replacing the string from right side of it,

```
my $string = 'GATGCAGTTAGGCGTAGCAGAGTGAGACGACGACGATATTAGGACCCGGTAAGGCACAATATAGC';
my %coord_colors = (
  10 => "red",
  48 => "orange",
  60 => "purple",
);

substr($string,$_,0) = $coord_colors{$_}
  for sort { $b <=> $a } keys %coord_colors;

print $string;
```

output

> GATGCAGTTAredGGCGTAGCAGAGTGAGACGACGACGATATTAGGACCCGorangeGTAAGGCACAATpurpleATAGC

using regex,

```
$string =~ s|.{$_}\K|$coord_colors{$_}|s
  for sort { $b <=> $a } keys %coord_colors;
```